# Javascript get time since last modification of a document

Tags: javascript

I am currently using document.lastModified() to find and display the time since a document was last modified. This displays the date and time, for example, like this: "07/26/2014 23:54:23". But I want the time elapsed since the document was modified last in a user readable format for example, like 4 hours 22 min, or 1 day 3 hours etc. What is the best way to achieve this. I know I am not being clear about the 'user readable' part, but what I mean is that the output should not be, atleast, like the number of milliseconds elapsed etc.

Comment: http://momentjs.com/.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Javascript date parsing library such as [moment.js](http://momentjs.com), or [XDate](http://arshaw.com/xdate/) if you want to leverage your current Javascript skills with the `Date()` object.